# Generating templates with separate models in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am creating an app that displays a series of data. I need to be able to filter this data by the column headings that are provided for the different categories of data displayed.

The filter itself is nice and basic. A select menu populated with the different columns for that chosen category, and then a simple text field that the user will populate to filter for.

This part is no problem. The issue comes when I need to add a new filter. By clicking the button to add a new filter, the template is added again, but of course has the same model on the select (for ngOptions) so updating one select menu value changes them all.

Here's the template code for the select:

```
<select name="header" class="form-control form-field" ng-model="filterSelect" ng-options="column | textFormat for column in filters">
    <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
</select>
```

This uses the following directive to recognise the tag and replace it with this template:

```
app.directive ('filterRow', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'js/templates/filter-row.html',
    }
});
```

Please also be aware that a user may wish to add multiple filters of the same field type, i.e. firstName = David || firstName = John || firstName = Jane || country = UK.

Many thanks